# where is the GOT[0] (global offset table) used?

Tags: linux, elf, dynamic-linking, got

I knew that "GOT[1] is point the Link_map struct" and "GOT[2] is point the _dl_runtime_resolver_". but I can't find place where GOT[0] is used.

anyone know where GOT[0] is used?

Answer (score 2):

The definitive reference for global offset table is [x86-64 psABI version 1.0](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/x86-64-psABI-1.0.pdf). It says:

> The tables first entry (number zero) is reserved to hold the address of the dynamic structure, referenced with the symbol _DYNAMIC.

Comment: thank you for answer :D. I knew it already. The point is is it a requirement? I mean, is it necessary? I was modified GOT[0] from early start of program even before "_start". and it did executed well. I want to use this reserved space as trampoline. did you know something about it?

Comment: `GOT[0]` is used by the dynamic linker. You should not use it.